# why is my first query slow but then it is fast?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

If I go to my site I get data from database. First Load is slow and takes 1-2 seconds. But then it is fast like 10ms. Why is the first connection slow? It is only when I use cassandra driver.

```
const http = require('http');

require('dotenv').config();

const { Client } = require('cassandra-driver');

const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

const routes = require('./src/routes/index');

const client = new Client({
  cloud: {
    secureConnectBundle: "secure-connect-weinf.zip",
  },
  keyspace: 'wf_db',
  credentials: {
    username: "username",
    password: "password",
  },
});

const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  await client.connect();
  const rs = await client.execute("SELECT * FROM employ_by_id;");
  console.log(rs);
  return res.json({
    message: 'Hello'
  })
});

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listen on port ${PORT}`)
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're seeing startup time initially, and then cached behavior after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is connecting (creating the TCP connections) the first time:

```js
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  await client.connect(); // <- this should be avoiding in the serve path
  const rs = await client.execute("SELECT * FROM employ_by_id;");
  console.log(rs);
  return res.json({
    message: 'Hello'
  })
});
```

To mitigate this, you can create the connections beforehard:

```js
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const rs = await client.execute("SELECT * FROM employ_by_id;");
  console.log(rs);
  return res.json({
    message: 'Hello'
  })
});

const server = http.createServer(app);
client.connect(err => {
  //TODO: Handle err
  // ...
  // Now that I'm connected to my DB, I can start serving requests
  server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listen on port ${PORT}`)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Reads from disk are always slower than reads from memory. When you query for the first time, Cassandra database reads from the disk which gets you a slow result. Second time Cassandra replies from the cached rows if caching is enabled, hence you get your results faster.
PS : Please dont execute "**select * from table**" queries, they are kind of anti pattern in Cassandra.

Comment: But I think cassandra is fast in write and read. how can a 1 Row take 1 second? In postgresql you can get 1-2million rows in 1 second

Comment: If you give a query with partition key then it will be fast. But you are querying without partition key, hence it is slow. If you had millions of data and you issue this query, you might get timeout exception. Cassandra needs to know where data is lying and if partition key is given then it is easy for Cassandra to query the proper node and get the results.  Without partition key data needs to be checked in each node. I have no experience with postgresql so cant comment with respect to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can I querying a partition key?

Comment: SELECT * FROM employ_by_id where key='ABC'; here key is the partition key which you have defined in table schema.

Comment: thanks now its work and its fast but please tell me one thing. How can I get this value ? [ Row { car_make: 'BMW' } ]

Comment: Probably this could help. https://www.datastax.com/blog/deep-look-cql-where-clause. Since Cassandra is a distributed database, and in scenarios where you have hundreds of nodes and you issue a query without partition key, then coordinator node would have to query on each node but if you give partition key (the data you want), coordinator can identify where to send the request and respond quickly.